# Drupal 7 giving incorrect module missing message

Tags: drupal

I am getting a PHP warning that says "User warning: the following module is missing from the system ..."  The message goes on to refer me to a documentation page that describes what to do to fix this issue.

Here's the problem:  The module is NOT missing from my system, and, when I compare the system table entry for the module's location with the actual location of the module in my files, they are identical.

So is there some other reason that I could be getting this message?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [Module Missing Message Fixer](https://www.drupal.org/project/module_missing_message_fixer) and follow the instructions.

> This module displays a list of missing modules that appear after the
>   Drupal 7.50 release and lets you fix the entries.